# Spring Boot error@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

Tags: java, spring, maven

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-21 14:07:24.292 ERROR 81885 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I tried to run the program using dependencies

Comment: You probably want to set `spring.datasource.url` in application.properties.

Comment: I already have added spring.datasource.url

Answer (score 0):

one of possible the cause problem is that  may  has some other `DataSourceAutoConfig`, first of all ,chekout out your `dependency` ,ensure there no extra  `DataSourceAutoConfig`. if you wont use database ,it is recommanded exclude all of them which `DataSourceAutoCOnfig Dependency` in your application；
and more stack error log  that can be verrrry useful for  troubleshooting the cause of  error .